# How would you set up url parametors with this infinite scroll script I have?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, parameters

I am using the following script.

http://www.inserthtml.com/2013/01/scroll-pagination/

It works great.

However, it works only for 1 page.  If I have multiple pages, it will run the same query results for all those pages.  I do not want that.

What I would like to do is have a different query result for each page.  Normally I have pages setup that have those queries results showing up.  Now I just need to add the function of those results with infinite scrolling.

How do I go on about doing that?

*UPDATE*

Here are the 3 files I have created for you to see my setup. The file names match the file names in the demo link above.

Can you please tell me where you would place your code in these files?

**index.php**

```
<?php

$hostname='127.0.0.1';
$username='root';
$password='';

$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=cave",$username,$password);
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="javascript.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//use.typekit.net/vue1oix.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">try{Typekit.load();}catch(e){}</script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

$('#content').scrollPagination({

nop     : 4, // The number of posts per scroll to be loaded
offset  : 0, // Initial offset, begins at 0 in this case
error   : 'No More Posts!', // When the user reaches the end this is the message that is
// displayed. You can change this if you want.
delay   : 500, // When you scroll down the posts will load after a delayed amount of  time.
  // This is mainly for usability concerns. You can alter this as you see fit
scroll  : true // The main bit, if set to false posts will not load as the user scrolls. 
  // but will still load if the user clicks.

});

});

</script>
<style>

h1 {
font-size: 50px;
}

</style>


</head>

<body>

<div id="content"> </div>


</body>
</html>
```

**ajax.php**

```
<?php
$hostname='127.0.0.1';
$username='root';
$password='';

$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=cave",$username,$password);

$offset = is_numeric($_POST['offset']) ? $_POST['offset'] : die();
$postnumbers = is_numeric($_POST['number']) ? $_POST['number'] : die();


$getPosts = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ".$postnumbers." OFFSET ".$offset);
$getPosts->execute();
$post = $getPosts->fetchAll();

if(count($post) > 0) {
foreach($post as $row) {

$title = $row['title']; 
$post = $row['post'];

?>
<h1><?php echo $title ?></h1>
<h3><?php echo $post ?></h3>
<?php
}
}
?>
```

**javascript.php**

```
(function($) {

    $.fn.scrollPagination = function(options) {

        var settings = { 
            nop     : 4, // The number of posts per scroll to be loaded
            offset  : 0, // Initial offset, begins at 0 in this case
            error   : 'No More Posts!', // When the user reaches the end this is the message that is
                                        // displayed. You can change this if you want.
            delay   : 500, // When you scroll down the posts will load after a delayed amount of time.
                           // This is mainly for usability concerns. You can alter this as you see fit
            scroll  : true // The main bit, if set to false posts will not load as the user scrolls. 
                           // but will still load if the user clicks.
        }

        // Extend the options so they work with the plugin
        if(options) {
            $.extend(settings, options);
        }

        // For each so that we keep chainability.
        return this.each(function() {       

            // Some variables 
            $this = $(this);
            $settings = settings;
            var offset = $settings.offset;
            var busy = false; // Checks if the scroll action is happening 
                              // so we don't run it multiple times

            // Custom messages based on settings
            if($settings.scroll == true) $initmessage = 'Scroll for more or click here';
            else $initmessage = 'Click for more';

            // Append custom messages and extra UI
            $this.append('<div class="content"></div><div class="loading-bar">'+$initmessage+'</div>');

            function getData() {

                // Post data to ajax.php
                $.post('ajax.php?page=' + page, {

                    action        : 'scrollpagination',
                    number        : $settings.nop,
                    offset        : offset,

                }, function(data) {

                    // Change loading bar content (it may have been altered)
                    $this.find('.loading-bar').html($initmessage);

                    // If there is no data returned, there are no more posts to be shown. Show error
                    if(data == "") { 
                        $this.find('.loading-bar').html($settings.error);   
                    }
                    else {

                        // Offset increases
                        offset = offset+$settings.nop; 

                        // Append the data to the content div
                        $this.find('.content').append(data);

                        // No longer busy!  
                        busy = false;
                    }   

                });

            }   

            getData(); // Run function initially

            // If scrolling is enabled
            if($settings.scroll == true) {
                // .. and the user is scrolling
                $(window).scroll(function() {

                    // Check the user is at the bottom of the element
                    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $this.height() && !busy) {

                        // Now we are working, so busy is true
                        busy = true;

                        // Tell the user we're loading posts
                        $this.find('.loading-bar').html('Loading Posts');

                        // Run the function to fetch the data inside a delay
                        // This is useful if you have content in a footer you
                        // want the user to see.
                        setTimeout(function() {

                            getData();

                        }, $settings.delay);

                    }   
                });
            }

            // Also content can be loaded by clicking the loading bar/
            $this.find('.loading-bar').click(function() {

                if(busy == false) {
                    busy = true;
                    getData();
                }

            });

        });
    }

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Where you call file.php within the JQuery, add a string as you normally would so the file.php page can pickup the querystring values. You can do this dynamically using whatever language you're using. If there aren't any variables that need to be passed like on the default page/page1 then don't send any. Pass those values to your DB query string. Best to parameterized values for the DB query. Basically you're going to pass the same info to the page via the querystring as you normally would through pagination buttons/links.

```
var parameters = "?page=2&category=cat&user=joe"
$.post('file.php' + parameters, {
    information        : 'to be sent',
    to                 : 'file'
    }, function(data) {
    }  
});
```

Comment: Sorry I am little confused.  Can you give me an example with a DB query and how it would interact with the javascript code shown above?